# Installing Windows7 on iMac which already has Windows

Tags: installation, operating-systems

friend of mine has iMac with Windows XP, without OS X. And here's the thing, is it possible to install Windows 7 on it? Because boot camp is not working or at least is not working as intended.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, there are many ways I'll list a few,
1- Start your windows xp, put your windows 7 disk in disk drive, open the drive and click on windows setup it will take you through the installation steps.

This will install windows 7 alongside of xp and you need to make sure that you are installing the same bit of os(32-bit /64 bit).

2- Using BootCamp https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201468

3- http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-mac-without-boot-camp/

Comment: Well that could be a problem... I need install Windows 7 64 bit but present Windows XP are 32 bit. And I can't really use point 2 and 3 because as I said - no OS X on that iMac :-(

Comment: You should have put that in your question, but in fact the question becomes the same for a Mac without OS X or a regular Windows PC. There's no straight upgrade path from XP to Win 7 anyway, even if you're going 32-32bit, [& none whatsoever to go from 32-64bit] so your only option is to wipe & install.

Comment: By "wipe" you mean what exactly? Disk formatting?

Comment: Yes. Clone the data off to another drive, format, install the new OS [if it will without bootcamp support - it's never wise to trash the OS X part of a Mac entirely, it gives you all kinds of headaches later], manually copy back what you can. There is no 'easy way' to get from XP to 7, or from 32 to 64 bit, even without trying to do it on a Mac with no OS X/recovery partition.